# Juntar informações corrrespondentes que estão em arrays diferentes no mesmo array

Tags: php

Quando o usuário da um `submit` no form, eu recebo os seguintes arrays (No caso tinha 3 produtos no form, se tiver apenas 1, nos 4 arrays teria apenas o indice 0, se tivesse 5 produtos, nos 4 arrays teriam indices 0, 1, 2, 3 e 4)

```
'tempero' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Ketchup' (length=7)
      1 => string 'Mustard' (length=7)
      2 => string 'Barbecue' (length=8)
  'quantidade' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
  'frequencia' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'FKetchup' (length=2)
      1 => string 'FMustard' (length=2)
      2 => string 'FBarbecue' (length=2)
  'combo' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'CKetchup' (length=2)
      1 => string 'CMustard' (length=2)
      2 => string 'CBarbecue' (length=2)
```

Meu problema é seguinte, eu precisaria juntar os itens correspondentes em arrays, no caso, precisaria de algo assim:

```
 'tempero1' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Ketchup' (length=7)
      1 => string '1' (length=7)
      2 => string 'FKetchup' (length=8)
      3 => string 'CKetchup' (length=8)
  'tempero2' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Mustard' (length=7)
      1 => string '2' (length=7)
      2 => string 'FMustard' (length=8)
      3 => string 'CMustard' (length=8)
  'tempero3' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Barbecue' (length=7)
      1 => string '3' (length=7)
      2 => string 'FBarbecue' (length=8)
      3 => string 'CBarbecue' (length=8)
```

Como eu poderia fazer para juntar os itens correspondentes em um único array, talvez utilizando um foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para criar um *array* da forma que explicou, basta utilizar a função `array_map` passando o primeiro parâmetro como `NULL`, assim será retornado um *array* com as combinações dos *arrays* de entrada. Por exemplo:

```
$tempero = ["Ketchup", "Mustard", "Barbecue"];
$quantidade = ["1", "2", "3"];
$frequencia = ["FKetchup", "FMustard", "FBarbecue"];
$combo = ["CKetchup", "CMustard", "CBarbecue"];

$saida = array_map(NULL, $tempero, $quantidade, $frequencia, $combo);
```

Gerará um *array* da forma:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ketchup
            [1] => 1
            [2] => FKetchup
            [3] => CKetchup
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mustard
            [1] => 2
            [2] => FMustard
            [3] => CMustard
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Barbecue
            [1] => 3
            [2] => FBarbecue
            [3] => CBarbecue
        )

)
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/ytpSEW).

Se estes *arrays* vem do POST, basta fazer algo como:

```
$saida = array_map(NULL, $_POST["temperos"], $_POST["quantidade"], ...);
```

Comment: Show de bola, era exatamente isso que eu estava buscando. Tinha tentado com diversas formas de `foreach`, mas no final das contas não precisava usar.

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar este código:

```
$temperos = array();
foreach($itens['tempero'] as $index => $item){
    $indice = 'tempero'.$index;
    $temperos[$indice] = array($item, $itens['quantidade'][$index], $itens['frequencia'][$index], $itens['combo'][$index]);
}
```